# Problems with hibernate validator- javax.persistence.RollbackException (spring)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I tried to insert validation into my maven project, but after that my project won't work anymore. Here is my code:

My entity class:

```
    @Table(name="Kandidati")
public class Candidate {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Size(min=13, max=13, message="JMBG mora imati 13 karaktera! ")
    private String upn;

    @Size(min=2, message="Ime mora imati najmanje 2 slova! ")
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Size(min=3, message="Prezime mora imati najmanje 3 slova! ")
    private String surname;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=4, message="Godina mora imati 4 broja! ")
    private int year;

    @Email(message="Greska! Email adresa nije validna!")
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Size(min=8, message="Telefon mora imati najmanje 8 karaktera! ")
    private String telephone;

    @Column(length=255)
    private String comment;

    @Size(min=2, max=2, message="Podatak treba da ima tacno 2 karaktera! ")
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String hired;
```

Ofcourse, there are getters and setters also, then in my .jsp page I put

```
            <form:errors path="name"></form:errors>
```

for every attribute, in dispatcher-servlet.xml I put

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

In my CandidateController class I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/kandidati", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute("candidate") Candidate candidate, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "newCandidate";

        }
        candidateService.save(candidate);
        return "newCandidate";
    }
```

When I launch the application with Tomcat, I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.save(Unknown Source)
        at BP.service.CandidateService.init(CandidateService.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:525)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:429)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:381)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
        ... 47 more
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: What is BP.service.CandidateService.init() doing?  From the stacktrace you posted it looks like: when Spring is initializing a post processor is calling CandidateService.init which calls the transactional method save and then failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer

I suspect this is the culprit:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=4, max=4, message="Godina mora imati 4 broja! ")
private int year;
```

[According to the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-spec), `@Size` can only be applied to `CharSequence`, `Collection`, `Map` and `arrays`.

To fix this, and replace the `@Size` annotation with `@Digits`.

```
@Digits(integer=4, message="Godina mora imati 4 broja! ")
private int year;
```

Considering an `int` can't ever be null, you can probably drop the `@NotNull` check as well (or keep it and turn the `int` into an `Integer`).

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thank you very much for this.